# Math.pow and Method Calling

Tags: java

I am writing a method to identify a polynomial functions from a given sequence of numbers.

```
public void updateSequence(Term t) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= sequence.length; i++) {                                      
        sequence[i] = sequence[i] - t(c) * Math.pow(i, t(e));
    }
}
```

I am having some problems with this method. I am unsure how to call a method called `getCoefficient` from another class called Term which is basically a method containing the following statement

```
return coefficient;
```

and then use that in the method above. I need to find the term which is basically `coefficient * i ^exponent` and then save it back into the sequence to be run through the iteration again.

These are the content of the term class.

```
public class Term {
    term = coefficient * x ^ exponent
    private double coefficient;
    private int exponent;

    public Term(double c, int e) {
        coefficient = c;
        exponent = e;
    }

    // returns the coefficient
    public double getCoefficient() {
        return coefficient;
    }

    // returns the exponent
    public int getExponent() {
        return exponent;
    }

    // returns the term as a String for display 
    // see the sample file for the layout required 
    public String display() {
       // TODO
       String tocompile = "tocompile";
       return tocompile;
    }
}
```

Comment: should be `t.getCoefficient()`

Comment: Share you method getCoefficient

Comment: Can you please show the contents of class `Term`?

Comment: its the same error if i use t.getCoefficient() and it just says cant find variable getCoefficient

Comment: actually. i figured that out. Mostly typos sorry. Um. I am not sure how to update the sequence now. Would that be now automatic as the sequence[i] = the whole thing ... so it would just automatically save in that array?

Comment: Thankyou guys, I think we are good except the updating thing i am still unsure about. But otherwise i think we are good. Thankyou so much. One of the best communities on the internet.